# inconsistent result from mdecrypt_generic

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to decrypt a file 'on the fly' using PHP. I am using the mdecrypt_generic function and I am decrypting the file in chunks instead of decrypting the whole file at once. The file I am decrypting is hosted on a remote server. I use cURL to retrieve the file in chunks and decrypt and output each chunk. This works fine when I start with the first chunk. But if I start with a different chunk (for example the second) mdecrypt_generic returns a different result for that chunk. Now the PHP manual says before every mdecrypt_generic call the encryption buffer has to be reinitialized. However, that just makes it worse, because when I do that it fails to decrypt all chunks except for the first (even if I start with the first). My code looks like this:

```
$td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'ctr', '');
$init = mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
foreach($chunks as $chunk=>$size){  
    $data = get_chunk($chunk,$size);
    echo mdecrypt_generic($td, $data);
}
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);
```

As I mentioned I do not reinitialize the encryption buffer before every mdecrypt_generic call, because that just breaks it completely.

**Edit 1 (Found the issue):**
I have found the issue, but not the solution. The issue was, the file is being decrypted in chunks, which means the current position is being remembered by the descriptor($td). However, I want to decrypt a file without having to start with the first chunk, but I would have to modify the descriptor in order to do that, but as far as I know there is no such option. The 'temporary' solution I use is starting with the decryption of random data which length equals the previous chunks, to get the correct descriptor position. But because some files are very large, this is a limited solution.

**Edit 2 (Found the solution):**
The file is encrypted in ctr mode, the $iv (initial value) is just like a counter and had to be increased after the decryption of each chunk.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the decryption routines allow for you to decrypt things in chunks?  Perhaps that first chunk has some kind of header or special data that relates to decryption that's missing in any other chunk.  Maybe you just can't do it this way.

Comment: @Crontab Yes, I am sure about that. Decrypting the file chunk by chunk works, but only if I start with the first one. Whenever I start with another chunk, it will return a totally different result. Simplified example: When I start with the first chunk, and proceed with the second, the decryption of the second chunk results in: A (correct). However, when I start with the second chunk the decryption of the second chunk results in: Z. This makes no sense. This is also the case when I reinitialize the encryption buffer before every call of mdecrypt_generic.